# Consulta SQL relación de muchos a muchos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy usando MySql. Tengo una relación de muchos a muchos usando tres tablas: eventos, instituciones y evento_institucion.

También tengo una tabla inscripciones que pertenece a eventos, está relacionada de una a muchos.

1. Un evento tiene muchas inscripciones
2. Eventos está relacionado con Instituciones de muchos a muchos con una tabla intermedia

Lo que necesito hacer es una consulta SQL que me traiga un listado de inscripciones, y a su vez saber saber las instituciones, ¿Me explico?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunté una imagen con las relaciones, debe recorrer inscripciones y saber el evento y las instituciones.

Espero me puedan ayudar

**UPDATE**
amigos... Les cuento que he tratado de resolver pero no sé cómo armar el SQL en una sola consulta.

Para obtener el listado de instituciones de un evento de la relación muchos a muchos, ejecuto la siguiente consulta:

```
select eventos.nombre, instituciones.nombre 
FROM instituciones
JOIN evento_institucion 
    ON evento_institucion.institucion_id = instituciones.id
JOIN eventos 
    ON eventos.id = evento_institucion.evento_id
where eventos.id = 1
```

Para obtener la inscripción con su código y el nombre del evento hago esto:

```
SELECT inscripciones.codigo, eventos.nombre 
FROM inscripciones
JOIN eventos ON inscripciones.evento_id = eventos.id
WHERE inscripciones.id = 1
```

Lo que quiero es hacer una sola consulta que me devuelva la inscripción, el evento y el listado de instituciones...

He hecho el esfuerzo en resolverlo pero no lo he logrado, por eso estoy pidiendo ayuda... Gracias...!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Siempre que hagas una pregunta, debes demostrar que has intentado hasta el momento. No basta con decir lo que queres, si no que probaste y donde fallaste.

Comment: Ya intentaste escribir la consulta?, Si tienes algun avance de tu consulta y no solo la imagen posteala para poder revisar en que podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Esta bastante fácil amigo, de hecho te ayudaría pero luego me ponen voto en contra por responder a preguntas sin ningún esfuerzo de desarrollo, te daré un par de consejos, deberías poner el mismo nombre de id en las tablas principales por ejemplo: en EVENTOS su id debería ser id_Eventos, eventos_id, etc; de esta forma cuando la escribas en tu query se te hará mas fácil estructurarlas, segundo si eres nuevo y no tienes ni idea de que hacer mejor empieza por usar sql server, se te hará  más fácil y además puedes usar el view para generar tu consulta con unos cuantos clics, espero que te sirva.

Comment: Así obtengo el nombre de los cursos de la relación de muchos a muchos: select eventos.nombre, instituciones.nombre 
FROM instituciones
JOIN evento_institucion ON evento_institucion.institucion_id = instituciones.id
JOIN eventos ON eventos.id = evento_institucion.evento_id
where eventos.id = 1

Answer (score 1):

para unir 2 consultar SQL puedes usar [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) es bastante simple.
Tu caso seria el siguiente.

```
select eventos.nombre, instituciones.nombre 
FROM instituciones
JOIN evento_institucion ON evento_institucion.institucion_id = instituciones.id
JOIN eventos ON eventos.id = evento_institucion.evento_id
where eventos.id = 1
UNION
select inscripciones.codigo, eventos.nombre from inscripciones
JOIN eventos ON inscripciones.evento_id = eventos.id
where inscripciones.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

No me suele gustar responder preguntas de SQL porque cuesta mucho montar un entorno para hacer las pruebas y responder sin probarlo da un poco de grima..

Dicho esto tu consulta debería funcionar con:

```
select eventos.nombre, instituciones.nombre, eventos.nombre, inscripciones.codigo 
FROM instituciones
JOIN evento_institucion 
    ON evento_institucion.institucion_id = instituciones.id
JOIN eventos 
    ON eventos.id = evento_institucion.evento_id
JOIN inscripciones
    ON inscripciones.evento_id = eventos.id
where eventos.id = 1 and inscripciones.id = 1
```

Fíjate que lo único que he hecho es añadir el JOIN a tu tabla de inscripciones.
Dicho esto entiendo que tendrás muchas inscripciones para una institución por lo que los registros serán del estilo:

```
institucion 1, evento 1, inscripcion 1
institucion 1, evento 1, inscripcion 2
institucion 1, evento 1, inscripcion 3
institucion 1, evento 2, inscripcion 1
....
```